# Pandas, Python: Pass names of dataframes to function in a loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have `n` dataframes, `df1, df2, df3,..., df_n` of arbitrary sizes and I want to pass them to various functions / methods. Passing them one at a time, `foo(df1)` to `foo(df_n)`, appears to be tedius, so I want to do it in a loop.

If I create a list `dfs = ['df1', 'df2',..., 'df_n']` and run a loop on the list and pass the elements, which are dataframe names, to the function, I am essentially passing strings and cannot perform the dataframe operations on strings inside the function. If I create a list `dfs = [df1, df2, ..., df_n]`, I still cannot seem to be able access the individual dataframes using `dfs[df1]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On constructing `dfs = [df1, df2, ..., df_n]`, each element is a dataframe object. You need to access them as regular list using index such as `dfs[0]`, `df[1]`.

As your requirement, you are better with constructing dictionary

```
dfs = {'df1': df1, 'df2': df2, 'df3': df3}
```

On dictionary above, call each sub-df as  `dfs['df1']`